# What kind of search algorithm does Xcode "open quickly" and Textmate "Go to file" use?

Tags: xcode, search, textmate

What type of search is this called? And how do they implement efficient searching of substring in this manner? Notice how when one type "empeee" it matches "**Emp** loy **ee** Vi **e** w.xib"

### Xcode

[image]

### TextMate

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name is "fuzzy matching" or "fuzzy search" or some variant. Wikipedia has an [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) about that.

Comment: I see. What kind of technology powers this kind of fuzzy search behind the scenes though? Is it Apple's searchkit or apache lucene or some other custom-made solution?

Comment: No idea, I don't do Objective C and your two examples are proprietary apps so I can't really look at the source. I don't think they use Lucene, it wouldn't seem "right" to me, and I don't know the specifics of searchkit but one could use the Levenshtein algorithm for that. I've used it in the past in PHP and it was very effective.